# Help identifing IC B20N02 CD10347

Tags: integrated-circuit

Need help to indentify this IC, i have googled for "CD10347", "B20", "N02". And can't get a match. Need the datasheep and a replacement part.

Thank you[image]

Comment: Ah it seens i was searching for B20N02 instead of B20N03, my mistake... Thank you for notice. Still can't find a CD10347, would a CGD0460 replace that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for [B20N03](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/B20N03/959832/1) and not 02

It's made by the Excelliance MOS corporation and is a MOSFET, 30V, 12A.

Comment: Ah it seens i was searching for B20N02 instead of B20N03, my mistake... Thank you for notice. Still can't find a CD10347, would a CGD0460 replace that?

Comment: That might be some batch code or date code. Given that it is only a MOSFET, finding a replacement from Fairchild or IR or TI shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: p.3 of the datasheet indicates that this is just a date code.

Comment: Yes part look equal to me, still i will ask seller. Better be safe.

Comment: @brhans Thank you, will order some, that solve my problem. Thank you for helping out